# algorithm for finding the number of 1s in a matrix (only vertical 1s). The image is self explanatory that what i exactly want

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix

Algorithm is required for Finding the group of 1s in a matrix, but the group of 1s should contain only vertical entry

[image]

Comment: You mean you can't figure out how to search columns in a matrix to find adjacent 1's? Stack Overflow really isn't about us doing your work for you. It's about us helping you improve your own work. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is more in the brain-teaser category.

For small matrices, we just access it column by column.

Assuming input is a 2 dimension array of integer, and output is a list of the following class:

```
class GroupIdentifier {
  int col;
  int rowStart;
  int colStart; 

  /* the corresponding getter/setter/constructor etc */
}
```

Here is the function you are looking for:

```
int FIRST_ONE = 2;
int IN_GROUP = 1;
int OUT_GROUP = 0;

public List<GroupIdentifier> findVerticalGroupsOf1 (int[][] a, 
  int numRow, int numCol) {
  List<GroupIdentifier> answer = new ArrayList<GroupIdentifier>();
  for (col = 0; col < numCol; col = col + 1) {
    // let's create the tempArr holding the current col
    int[] tempArr = new int[numRow];
    for (row = 0; row < numRow; row = row + 1 =) {
      tempArr[row] = a[row][col];
    }
    // let's find the groups
    // first, init the state
    int state = (tempArr[0] == 1) ? FIRST_ONE : OUT_GROUP;
    int start = (state == FIRST_ONE) ? 0 : -1;
    // I see this problem as a simple state-machine
    // We have three states: FIRST_ONE encountered (0 to 1),
    // still tracking the 1s IN_GROUP ... (1 to 1) and 
    // get OUT_GROUP (1 to 0). 
    // the switch case in the following loop does exactly that.
    // So, whenever we get an OUT_GROUP event, we get an answer.
    for (int i = 1; i < numRow; i = i + 1) { // edit: changed to numRow as
                                             // it was a typo error
      switch (state) : 
      case FIRST_ONE :
        if (tempArr[i] == 0)
          state = OUT_GROUP;
        else 
          state = IN_GROUP; 
        break;
      case IN_GROUP :
        if (tempArr[i] == 0) {
          GroupIdentifier gi = new GroupIdentifier (col, start, i - 1);
          answer.add(gi); 
        }
        break; 
      case OUT_GROUP :
        if (tempArr[i] == 1) {
          start = i; 
          state = FIRST_ONE;
        } 
        break; 
    }

  }
  // since this question looks like homework,
  // i will leave out the boundary case handling
  // here. it's not that hard; just copy/paste the
  // switch statement and fondle around.
  return answer; 
}
```

As a computer scientist myself, I think of ways to optimize it.

For larger matrices, what I would do is to precompute the all combinations of tempArr and store them as Integer --> List  map. Then, I will traverse the columns without computing again.

Comment: @EdwardAung can you please explain this code. i am confuse in the logic being used for vertical grouping. It will be much more better if you could write the full code in Java. Thanks

Comment: @user8409309 ... edited the answer to include comments explaining the code (as well as corrected a typo error). And my code is in pure Java (not even use any known libraries).

Comment: can you please send me the full java code?. i worked around this function but i couldnt implement it. Thank you